# Numeric precision as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, precision, numeric

```
Declare @Precision INTEGER
Set @precision  = 3
```

-> I have a select statement here which selects the integer value

and if their is a way that I can use this @precision in numeric data type for example something like this

```
numeric(20,@precision)
```

Comment: What database are you using?  And what are you trying to accomplish?  There is perhaps a better way than using a variable for precision.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server well what I'm trying to accomplish is to get rid of the trailing zeros I'm casting my value into varchar after that I reverse it and find the precision then I reverse it back cat it into numeric data type and that their I need my precision value so my numeric cast will look like this Cast(MyNumber as numeric(20,@precision))

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `str()` function (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)).

It allows you to convert numerics to strings, while controlling the precision.

For instance:

```
select str(3.14158165, 5, 3)
```

Returns `'3.142'`.